# compare two table with each other and show the result of that another one using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

here is my php code in other pages everything works correctly , but in this page I do not know what is the problem, the code should work like this => it should select data from tour_sys_user and if tour_user_hotel will be BKK it show another table with name of BKK hotels . but it is not working. kindly help me

```
        $us_ck_qr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tour_sys_user WHERE tour_sys_user='$_SESSION[tour_sys_user]'");
        $us_ck_num=mysql_num_rows($us_ck_qr);
        if($us_ck_num==1){
            while($hotel_qr=mysql_fetch_array($us_ck_qr)){
                if($hotel_qr[tour_user_hotel]=="BKK"){
                    $hotel_qr2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bangkok_hotel");
                    while($hotel_sh=mysql_fetch_array($hotel_qr2)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?>"><?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?></option>
                    <?
                    }
                }elseif($hotel_qr[tour_user_hotel]=="PTY"){
                    $hotel_qr2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pattaya_hotel");
                    while($hotel_sh=mysql_fetch_array($hotel_qr2)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?>"><?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?></option>
                    <?
                    }
                }elseif($hotel_qr[tour_user_hotel]=="HKT"){
                    $hotel_qr2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phuket_hotel");
                    while($hotel_sh=mysql_fetch_array($hotel_qr2)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?>"><?=$hotel_sh[hotel_name];?></option>
                    <?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```